# capital letters in a name of a company

Tags: capitalization

If a name of a company contains the word "and", should we capitalize the first letter "a" in this word?

> Limited Liability Company Horns And Hoofs

Do we have to capitalize the first letters in **all** words included in a name of a company?

Comment: This is informative: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case#Case_styles. I normally use #4: "Capitalisation of the first word, and all other words, except for articles, prepositions, conjunctions, and forms of to be". However, it'd be the best to follow your manual of style.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you should follow the capitalization pattern adopted by the company itself. To cite an example, "Procter and Gamble" does not capitalize the conjunction "and".

Some Russian companies use English names composed entirely of capital letters. Some capitalize a letter in the middle of their name, like PhosAgro. There's a variety of styles.

If the company has no official English name for some reason, then it all depends on the importance of being precise in such a literal way. If it's a legal translation, one should consult the involved parties, legal experts.

If its a news article translation, one might ask the publisher what is their policy in this regard. If there's no particular policy, I would use Damkerng T.'s suggestion as most appropriate: "Capitalisation of the first word, and all other words, except for articles, prepositions, *conjunctions*, and forms of to be".

Comment: Some use an ampersand instead. B&Q is the first that springs to mind.

Comment: @CopperKettle thanks. The company in question does not have an adopted name in English.

Comment: @Humbulani: then it all depends on whether it is important to be precise to the extreme. If it's not a legal translation but a translation for a news report, say, I'd use the rules of stylistic thumb quoted by Damkerng T. and go with a small-case conjunction *and*.  (0:

Comment: @CopperKettle I am not translating any texts. My friend wants to open a representative office in Madagascar. She is running a business in South Africa. She consulted a translation agency that proposed a translation of the name of her company. But only the first letter of the first word was capitalized in the company's name translated into English. Because I speak English well enough, I decided to ask native speakers of English.

Comment: @Tetsujin, great idea! I think an ampersand is the most suitable for the company's name in English in this context.

Comment: 'hoofs' bothers me too - but if that's the actual company name, it would be hard to change - see [NGRAM](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hoofs%2C+hooves&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Choofs%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chooves%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @Humbulani, I see now. I replied from my standpoint. You might also try asking at [ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions), there are more native English speakers there. Tetsujin: is the problem with "Hoofs" the fact that it's not a proper noun?

Comment: @Tetsujin As I see from Ngram, 'hooves' is more popular today. Maybe I will recommend this word to her. Let me tell it to you straight, 'hoofs' began bothering me either. Her business is related to safaris, i.e. hunting cape buffalo and so on.

Comment: I had to look up hoofs, thinking it was simply 'wrong' - I was actually surprised to learn it was a previously popular form. Times change, I guess. I'm sure I vaguely remember from school, something along the lines of "watch out for roof/roofs & hoof/hooves etc"